# string.IndexOf exact match

Tags: indexof

I have the following:

```
string text = "Select [id] AS [FROMId] FROM [TASK] ORDER BY id"
```

and I want to use `text.IndexOf("FROM")` in order to find where the FROM starts.

I want to find the position of FROM and not the position of FROMId.

`LastIndexOf` or `FirstIndexOf` are not correct answers cause the text could be anything like

```
string text = @"Select [id] AS [FROMId], 
                newId as [newFROMId] FROM [TASK] ORDER BY [FROMId]"
```

I need the indexof to do exact matching.

Any ideas?

Comment: How about using Regex with a [word-boundary `\b` check](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)? Like e.g. `"\bFROM\b"` as the pattern.

Comment: @UweKeim, I suspect all edge cases will best be done with a proper parser.  Even word boundaries wont help with `select 'got data from unit ' | unit from dtable ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `FROM` is an SQL reserved word that will generally have spaces on either side, you could look for that then, since that will give you the address of the space *before* the `F`, add one to get the location of the `F` itself:

```
int index = text.IndexOf(" FROM ") + 1
```

This may not necessarily take care of *all* edge cases<sup>(a)</sup> but, to do that properly, you may have to implement an SQL parser to ensure you can correctly locate the real `from` keyword and distinguish it from other possibilities.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Such as things like:

```
select [a]FROM[tble] ...
select 'got data from unit #' | unit from tbl ...
```

and so on.

Comment: Are you sure? How about `\t`, `\r` or `\n`?

Comment: Also: `SELECT *FROM[MyTable]` also works in SQL Server, for example.

Comment: @Uwe Keim Can you give more details? The answers from paxdiablo and Murf worked but they are a little a bit hacky

Comment: @Uwe, those characters are certainly possible but unusual. I've updated the answer to show why anything short of a full parser probably won't catch all edge cases. Sometimes it's easier to restrict the input data :-)